# How I can see all my last site contents (news) in Google search results?

Tags: sitemap, google-crawlers

I have news magazine site  that collect news from on-line newspaper and sites.
Site content and first page changes every 2-5 minutes (because find new news and i my first page display last news list).Google find my 2-3 age news of my site content.
what is wrong and what should i do.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to read about and address Google's Crawler frequency criteria:

You can read the article here: https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40392?hl=en